# How to get the values(with Javascript) out of an php jsonObject(database entries)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get values out of a database table and put them into a pdf document with javascript. I got the jsonobject from my php script but if I am trying to get the values it says "undefine".

```php
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=onlinebestellung', 'root', '');
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, 1);

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM artikelbestellung ');
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $json=json_encode($result);
            echo $json;
```

```
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'includes/rechnung.php',
                     success: function(result) {
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
                    alert(jsonData);
                     /* alert(jsonData); */
                     var pdf2 = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
                     pdf.text ("Test:" + jsonData.artikelnummer , 20, 80);
                     pdf.save ("rechnung123.pdf");

    }
});
```

alert shows: "object Object".
my database table has 4 fields(id, rechnungsnummer, artikelnummer, anzahl)

Comment: don't alert it, `console.log` it. Then access properties like this `myObject.whateverProperty`. You'll see what you need to call in the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your javascript code to follow:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'includes/rechnung.php',
    success: function(result) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
        var pdf2 = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
        pdf.text ("Test:" + jsonData[0].artikelnummer , 20, 80);
        pdf.save ("rechnung123.pdf");
    }
});
```

As you can see when you fetch the data from database it will add it to array with index and to access the value you need to call the row number as index and then the column name itself.

I hope this helps.

Let me know if you need more help to this.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly.